# Assembly x86_64 displays residual values

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I want to take a number from the console and to display it incremented by 1. But the outcome is not what I want to display. Can you explain to me what I did wrong? (I am not advanced in assembly at all)

```
.data
number: .long 0
numberformat: .asciz "%ld"
assig: .asciz "text \n \n"
enternumber: .asciz "Enter the number: \n"
numberformat1: .asciz "The input number+1 = %d \n"

.text
.global main
main:           # main
    call print1
    call print2
    call inout
    call exit

inout:
    movq $0, %rax    # clear rax
    movq $numberformat, %rdi    # load format string
    movq $number, %rsi    # set storage to address of number
    call scanf
    pop %rbp
    movq $number, %rbx
    add $1, %rbx
    movq $0, %rax
    movq %rbx, %rsi
    movq $numberformat1, %rdi
    call printf    
    # call printnewnumber
    ret

print1:
    movq $0, %rax
    movq $assig, %rdi
    call printf
    ret

print2:
    movq $0, %rax
    movq $enternumber, %rdi
    call printf
    ret

printnewnumber:
    movq $0, %rax
    movq %rdx, %rsi
    movq $numberformat1, %rdi
    call printf    
    ret
```

Comment: "But the outcome is not what I want to display" - so what is the program actually printing?

Comment: The program displays(I think) residual values as I said in the title. If I run the program I will always get the same number in the console (which is not the number I wrote incremented by 1)

Comment: Don't use Javascript snippet tags for assembly code.  That doesn't work.

Comment: On which system are you trying to execute the program? Which assembler are you using?

Comment: I'm using Debian with AT&T syntax(x86_64 assembly) and I compile with gcc

Comment: `pop %rbp` is totally weird there.  You're popping your return address off the stack so when the `ret` at the bottom of `inout` returns, it's actually returning to `main`'s return address.  The `call exit` is never reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `movq $number, %rbx` does not copy the input number itself, but just the *address* of it. If you *dereference* the pointer, you get the desired output:

Changing the aforementioned line to

```
movq number(%rip), %rbx   # Dereference pointer and store input number in RBX
```

yields

```
Assignment 1b: inout

Enter the number:
123
The input number+1 = 124
```

Comment: Not the hero we deserved, but the hero we needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why would you want to use the address as a 32-bit absolute immediate in a separate instruction (sign-extended to 64-bit: `movq` instead of `movabs`)?  Use `mov number(%rip), %rbx` like a compiler would.  Or if you really want a 32-bit absolute, use `mov number, %rbx` like you would in 32-bit code (without RIP-relative addressing).  That also works in a non-PIE executable but is inefficient.  The normal way to address static data is RIP-relative.

Comment: I don't entirely get that. Why would `movq $number, %rbx` move a 32-bit immediate? Isn't that an explicit qword move? Anyway, thank you for pointing out the correct syntax, I'm still struggling to learn AT&T syntax and apparently wasn't able to figure out how to do it completely right - I'm usually using NASM, where `mov rbx, qword [rel number]` would have been the way to go. I didn't have the idea to use explicit `rip`-relative addressing here, which I never need when writing NASM assembly (well, now I know, that `rel` is actually the same ;) ). I've edited the answer.

Comment: Alright, got it. The `mov` instruction only allows loading/storing to 64-bit immediate addresses, if the `rax` register is used ([`MOV RAX,moffs64*`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov)). Thank you for that hint, I'm learning a lot here :)

Comment: @JanWichelmann: Look at disassembly for `movq`  vs. `movabs`.  Last I checked, only `movabs` used a 64-bit absolute immediate for an address, IIRC.  But of course both of those are bad vs. a RIP-relative LEA if you want an address in a register.  And of course there's no reason to do that.  Intel-syntax `mov` includes both `movq` (32-bit immediate sign-extended, or 64-bit mov with a normal addressing mode) and `movabsq` (64-bit immediate or 64-bit absolute load/store).  You don't want absolute addresses; RIP + rel32 addressing modes are the most compact way to address static data.

Comment: Oh yeah, I wrote an answer about this a while ago. 
 See [Difference between movq and movabsq in x86-64](//stackoverflow.com/q/40315803) compares for AT&T vs. NASM with disassembly.  Also [How do RIP-relative variable references like "\[RIP + \_a\]" in x86-64 GAS Intel-syntax work?](//stackoverflow.com/q/54745872) for NASM vs. GAS's AT&T and Intel syntaxes